# Android gradle - shared variable between Android and Dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In Gradle how can I access to a global variable?

Assuming I have an external library called: "myLib-1.0.aar", I would like to do:

```
def myVar = "myLib-1.0"

    android {
        ...

        defaultConfig {...}

        buildTypes {
            ...
            buildTypes.each {
                buildConfigField "String", "myVarName", "$myVar"
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        compile(name: '$myVar', ext: 'aar')
        ...
    }
```

What am I missing here? I want to have the variable on BuildConfig object, and at the same time, set the same value for library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$`-based string interpolation does not work with single-quoted strings in Groovy (and, hence, Gradle). If you are expecting `'$myVar'` to expand into `myLib-1.0`, use double-quotes (`"$myVar"`), as you are `buildConfigField`.